# AES-128 encryption produce different result

Tags: linux, shell, encryption, openssl, aes

I want to encrypt `"hello"` text using `"123456789"` key with `AES-128` bit encryption cipher, so i go to https://aesencryption.net/ site and tried to encrypt. It gives me result in base64 as `44VUz6QR9WOx3tIzrTVKIg==`

Now on linux machine i tried same with `openssl` cli (with hex converted key and without hex), but it doesnt produce the same result as above website.

`echo -n "hello" | ./openssl aes-128-cbc -K 313233343536373839 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -a`

OUTPUT:`hd7d6N4iUsaeFnp76ZgnmA==`

`echo -n "hello" | ./openssl aes-128-cbc -k 123456789 -iv 00000000000000000000000000000000 -a -nosalt`

OUTPUT: `U7lXytP7pnVcOPwi8Hjd7A==`

So anyone tell me what am i missing?

Comment: Look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/should-aes-always-give-the-same-output#42649 ( Should AES always give the same output? )

Comment: How do you know that the online site uses a zero vector as IV (or CBC as mode, PKCS#7 as padding, etc.)? None of the parameters are disclosed. Not a very trust inspiring site (though this is true for many online crypto sites).

Comment: @Topaco.  To see what parameters are used, just look at the source code for that page. It is all there in the source.  And, yes, the IV is different.

Comment: @Topaco im sure that website using `aes-128-cbc` and `0` as iv vector. i know this because im using that site to decrypt `aes` encrypted `.json` data. And i get 100% accuracy in decryption. since i have many json files which needs to decrypt so i can't rely on site, because its time consuming. so im trying to decrypt using `openssl`.

Comment: @Claudio if `-iv` is zero then output should be the same i guess

Comment: @fpmurphy I guess that website code is for example/educational purpose. But behind the scene there is something else :)

Comment: The parameters used can be determined: The site applies AES-128 in CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding. The too short key is extended with 0x00 values to the required length of 16 bytes. As static IV the Utf-8 encoding of *12345678b0z2345n* (hex encoded *0x313233343536373862307a323334356e*) is used, s. [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zxK). Further encryption/decryption with these parameters confirms these assumptions, s. [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zxL). Note that a wrong IV for AES/CBC corrupts only the first block (which may have gone unnoticed in your decryptions).

Comment: @fpmurphy - There are three different source codes. And even using the first source code as basis: If the IV is wrong, why should the mode be the right one? No, in the end you have to guess and test out the parameters. In my opinion an example for a bad crypto site (apart from the fact that neither mode, nor IV or any encodings can be set).